# Ubuntu, Skype and Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, skype, skype4py

I am using Skype4Py and create a skype bot.
I wanted to install the bot on a linux enviroment (Ubuntu 12.04 as I recall right)
And I installed skype and the bot + dependicies.

Now whenever I ask for message.Chat.Type, it gives me a command timeout..

Any solution?

error:

```
Exception in thread Skype4Py MessageStatus event scheduler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Skype4Py/utils.py", line 225, in run
handler(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "functions/messageProcessor.py", line 161, in processMessages
 if allowed(message, "url_parse"):
File "functions/messageProcessor.py", line 62, in allowed
 chatType = message.Chat.Type
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Skype4Py/chat.py", line 405, in _GetType
    return str(self._Property('TYPE'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Skype4Py/chat.py", line 33, in _Property
 return self._Owner._Property('CHAT', self.Name, PropName, Value, Cache)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Skype4Py/skype.py", line 296, in _Property
 value = self._DoCommand('GET %s' % jarg, jarg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Skype4Py/skype.py", line 276, in _DoCommand
 self.SendCommand(command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Skype4Py/skype.py", line 778, in     SendCommand
 self._Api.send_command(Command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Skype4Py/api/posix_x11.py", line 445, in  send_command
 raise SkypeAPIError('Skype command timeout')
SkypeAPIError: Skype command timeout
```

Comment: Post your source code, how can we help if we can't see what's wrong?

Comment: I guess the source code is too big to show lol...
It is made out of lot's of files + it works perfectly fine on windows..

It only happened when used on linux + skype when it goes through the message processor where I call message.Chat.Type. Which would give me a Chat object and I want to get the type of that object (GROUP, etc)

Comment: What type is `message`? Is this the only API call that triggers this error?

Comment: as far as I can come, yes it's the only error the API triggers.

Comment: message is Skype4Py.Message Object